# Get part of redux state in server calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a use case where I want to make a server call with the latest redux state. I thought of passing copy of state down the method flow and then call action creater with state. It is possible that value of state could have been changed by the time actual server call happens.

One possible way of getting copy of state is by using getState() in actions before making a server calls. But with this approach, I will be exposing global state which is an anti-pattern.

Is there any better way around it?

To give an example, my code looks like this.

**App.js**

```
executeAction(selectedData)
```

**actions.js**

```
function executeAction(selectedData) {
    // execute Worker threads
    // Takes around 20 seconds
    onWorkerThreadResolution(selectedData)
}

function onWorkerThreadResolution(selectedData) {
    // Make server call with selectedData as an argument
}
```

There is a high possibility that someone might have updated selectedData in redux state through another UI action.

Comment: using getState should be fine or you can reconstruct you object from getState to cherry pick whatever values you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Redux doc](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) action is plain JavaScript object. So I think you mean action creator, which in your case will be [async action creator](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators).

The common logic is to use Redux-thunk to make server calls. When making server call you pass only required arguments to it and not full state. When call is completed successfully or erroneously, you call dispatch from your action creator with new data. The best way to do it is to return Promise from your server call function to action creator. (Server calls may not be implemented with fetch as in example. It is up to you how to implement them.)

So the state is changed when server provides some response or request timeout happens.